# Date issue uib-datepicker and $filter Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-filter

I'm dealing with an issue with dates format:
in my formular I'm using uib-datepicker-popup to get the calendar and in the controller I need to format this date so I'm using a `$filter('date')`,

so here is the input field:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="fechasolicitudc" type="text" class="form-control"
        ng-class="(form.fechasolicitudc.$invalid) && (submitted) ? 'error': '' "
        ng-style="(form.fechasolicitudc.$invalid) && (submitted) && {'background-color':'pink'}"
        name="fechasolicitudc" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
        ng-model="vm.peticion.contacto.fechaSol" 
        is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.fechasolicitudc"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            ng-click="vm.openCalendar('fechasolicitudc')">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

and in my controller:

```js
if (vm.peticion.contacto.fechaSol != null) {
    var d = $filter('date')(vm.peticion.contacto.fechaSol, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    vm.peticion.contacto.fechaSol = d;
}
```

what happenes is that the date is updated in the DB but the field becomes erased.
When I try give the input `type="date"` the field is not erased but the calendar popup does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In your markup:

```
//...
uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}" ng-model="vd"
datepicker-options="vdOptions"
// ...
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.dateFormat = 'dd MMM yyyy';  // or your custom date

// and if you want to have your date set as today
$scope.vd = new Date();
$scope.vdOptions = {
      formatYear: 'yy',
      formatMonth: 'MM',
      maxDate: new Date(),
      minDate: minDate,
      startingDay: 1,
      showWeeks: false,
      yearRows: 2,
      yearColumns: 2
};
```

`vd` = valueDate

I do not see the point of using `$filter` in this case.

Comment: in my DB the format is yyyy-MM-dd and the datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}" changes just the appearence of the date not its format, if i don't do the $filter the insert in the DB does not work (i don'treally understand why)

Comment: I have updated the answer with the vdOptions property where you can customise your date options